# Expresiones lambda - ¿Como ordenar con más de un atributo?

Tags: java, lambda, filtro, ordenamiento

Tengo un problema con expresiones **lambda** y necesito resolver un método. Para comenzar os adjunto un código y verlo más claro.

Clase *Person*:

```
public class Person {
private String id, name, surname;
private LocalDate birthdate;
private double weight;


public Person(String id, String name, String surname, LocalDate birthdate, double weight) {
    super();
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
    setSurname(surname);
    setBirthdate(birthdate);
    setWeight(weight);
}

//getters y setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getSurname()+", "+getName()+" ("+getId()+") : "+getWeight();
}
```

Y ahora la clase *Check*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add(new Person("11111-A","David","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),63.2));
    people.add(new Person("14111-A","Elena","Lazaro",LocalDate.now(),60));
    people.add(new Person("13111-A","Marina","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),17.3));
    people.add(new Person("12111-A","Manuel","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),91));


    people.sort();              
    System.out.println(people);

}
```

Este es el esqueleto del código. Debo usar el método **sort** para ordenar el *ArrayList* primero por apellido, en caso de empate,  por nombre y, en caso de empate, por los que tengan menor peso. Para ello he usado la siguiente línea:

```
people.sort((p1, p2) ->{p1.getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getSurname());
                            if(p1.getSurname()==p2.getSurname()) {
                                p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
                            } else if(p1.getName()==p2.getName()) {

                            }
    });
```

Lo dicho, quiero ordenar por apellido primero, si este es el mimso, por nombre, y si este vuelve a ser el mismo, por menor a mayor peso. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Por apellido solamente puedo hacerlo sin problemas:

```
        people.sort((p1, p2) ->p1.getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getSurname()));
```

Pero no se incluirle la comparación de más atributos, como he escrito el código arriba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde la introducción de la programación funcional en Java 8, el tema de las comparaciones se simplificó sobremanera. Mi recomendación es usar los métodos estáticos que brinda la interfaz [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
    people.sort(
            // Comparo por nombre ascendente (por defecto)
            Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                    // Si la comparación anterior resulta en igualdad comparo por apellido
                    .thenComparing(Person::getSurename)// 
                    // Si ambas comparaciones anteriores resultan en igualdad comparo por peso
                    .thenComparingDouble(Person::getWeight)
    );
```

Todas las comparaciones por defecto se hacen en modo ascendente, si se desea que cualquiera sea en modo descendente simplemente hay que hacer uso del método [Comparator.reversed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) que invierte el sentido del comparador.

```
    people.sort(
            Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                    .thenComparing(Person::getSurename)
                    .thenComparing(
                         Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getWeight)
                                   .reversed()
                    )
    );
```

Como puedes ver ahora la comparación del peso la hago de mayor a menor. El método `reversed()` no lo puedo aplicar sobre el comparador del primer ejemplo porque invertiría el orden de toda la comparación. Por tanto al método `thenComparing()` le tengo que pasar un nuevo comparador específico para el peso, ahora si con el orden invertido.

Puede parecer un poco complicado en un inicio pero créeme que cuando le agarras el truco puedes hacer comparaciones bien complejas de un modo relativamente sencillo.

**Edición según comentario:**

> ¿Cómo podría realizar esto mismo pero con expresiones lambda? Es por entender mejor ambas opciones.

Solo recordar que las expresiones lambda en Java son una mera simplificación del modo de implementar una interfaz funcional (interfaz con un único método abstracto).

Por lo dicho en el parráfo anterior si queremos hacer lo mismo con expresiones lambda tenemos 2 opciones:

1 - Definir un comparador según nuestras necesidades y pasarlo directamente al método `sort()`.

```
    Comparator<Person> personComparator = (p1, p2) -> {
        int compName = p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
        if (compName != 0) {
            return compName;
        }

        int compSurename = p1.getSurename().compareTo(p2.getSurename());
        if (compSurename != 0) {
            return compSurename;
        }

        return (int) (p1.getWeight() - p2.getWeight());
    };

    people.sort(personComparator);
```

2 - Definir un comparador para cada atributo que queremos comprar y luego hacer uso de los mísmos método estáticos de la interfaz `Compaartor`.

```
    people.sort(
            // Notar que n1 y n2 son los nombres de las personas a comparar
            Comparator.comparing(Person::getName, (n1, n2) -> n1.compareTo(n2))
                    .thenComparing(Person::getSurename, (s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2))
                    .thenComparing(Person::getWeight, (w1, w2) -> (int) (w1 - w2))
    );
```

***NOTA IMPORTANTE:*** Como se puede observar en el caso de los comparadores casi siempre el modo más fácil, y limpio, de implementarlos el usando los métodos estáticos de la interfaz `Comparator` junto con métodos de referencia.

Comment: ¿Cómo podría realizar esto mismo pero con expresiones lambda? Es por entender mejor ambas opciones. La que tu me has mandado me funciona correctamente pero quería conocer el mundo de las expresiones lambda que es algo que no encuentro por internet con ejemplos un poco más complicados que comparar un solo atributo con otro. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Jultorral, te acabo de poner la edición para usar expresiones lambda. De todos modos te recomiendo, aunque se que loque deseas es aprender a usar estas expresiones, que no quieras usarlas en todos sitios porque sí. En el caso de los comparadores que necesitas, hacer uso de estas solo hace el código más extenso y menos legible. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer el sort usando Collections.sort(), que lleva la List a ordenar y un Comparator que puede ser escrito como lambda.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    people.add(new Person("11111-A","David","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),63.2));
    people.add(new Person("14111-A","Elena","Lazaro",LocalDate.now(),60));
    people.add(new Person("13111-A","Marina","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),17.3));
    people.add(new Person("12111-A","Manuel","Garcia",LocalDate.now(),91))

    Collections.sort(people, 
                    (p1,p2) -> p1.getSurname().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getSurname())
    );

    List<Person> resultado = 
        people.stream()
            .filter((p) -> p.getweight() < 80.0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(Person p : resultado) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podría hacer la comparación primero de apellido, después de nombre y finalmente de peso? En el momento que incluyo más filas en el cuerpo, me da error

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta lo estás queriendo hacer asi lo veo.

Comment: No entiendo que me quieres decir, pero básicamente lo que necesito es hacer una ordenación de la lista mediante sort() comparando primero apellidos, después, si hay diferentes personas con el mismo apellido, ordenarlos por nombre, y por ultimo, si tienen apellido y nombre iguales, ordenar de menos a mayor peso. No encuentro nada de esto por ningún lado, o no se interpretarlo bien.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una forma de hacer mediante expresiones lambda el orden de 3 atributos (String, String, Double) de la siguiente forma:

```
        Comparator<Person> comparadorA = (p1, p2) ->p1.getSurname().compareTo(p2.getSurname());
    Comparator<Person> comparadorB = comparadorA.thenComparing((p1,p2)->p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()));
    Comparator<Person> comparadorC = comparadorB.thenComparing((p1,p2)->Double.compare(p1.getWeight(), p2.getWeight()));
    people.sort(comparadorC);
```

A ver que os parece y si se puede mejorar, seguro que sí!